# Resample Python pandas exclude some fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Ehy guys, 
I have a dataset like this:

```
                      index                           uid     level   sec
Time
2019-12-16 01:38:30    257  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      wake    30
2019-12-16 01:39:00    258  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light  5520
2019-12-16 03:11:00    259  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2       rem   480
2019-12-16 03:19:00    260  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light   660
2019-12-16 03:19:00    260  HFxeriowjryghdsjuihdjsuiuiw3    light   660
```

I want apply a resample on this dataset on 15 minutes.
I applied a

```
data =dataM.reset_index().set_index('time').resample('15min').mean()
```

and i have this output:

```
                    index     sec
time                                   
2019-12-16 01:30:00  257.500000  2775.0
2019-12-16 01:45:00         NaN     NaN
2019-12-16 02:00:00         NaN     NaN
2019-12-16 02:15:00         NaN     NaN
2019-12-16 02:30:00         NaN     NaN
2019-12-16 02:45:00         NaN     NaN
2019-12-16 03:00:00  259.000000   480.0
2019-12-16 03:30:00  260.000000   1300.0
```

My problem that I want keep some fields that I don't want to resample: 
My output should be :

```
                      index                           uid        sec
Time
2019-12-16 01:30:00    257  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2        2775
2019-12-16 03:00:00    259  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2        480
2019-12-16 03:15:00    260  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2        660
2019-12-16 03:15:00    260  HFxeriowjryghdsjuihdjsuiuiw3        660
```

Because some fields should be the same of the initial dataset (because ID don't be changed, and index too)

In this type of downgrade, it useful to use a mean or sum?
This data is time to sleep of people (given an ID)
I tried both the operator and i think that sum should be better in this case, because with mean I lose some information (i think), instead of with sum I just keep the data, first or before.

In this example, the sum (time of sleep) in 1:38 is a 5550 in 1:30 am
With mean is just a 1.30 am sleep only 2775 second.
The graph will be different.

**EDIT: with different iD with the same time I don't want that compute mean of the second, but calculate two different value for different IDs.**

I tried to use a groupby function on resample but I had a strange behavior:

```
data =dataM.groupby('uid').resample('15min').mean().dropna()
```

in this way the initial data :

```
2019-12-17 02:04:30    273  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      wake    30
2019-12-17 02:05:00    274  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light  5010
2019-12-17 03:28:30    275  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      deep   270
2019-12-17 03:33:00    276  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light    30
2019-12-17 03:33:30    277  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      deep   360
2019-12-17 03:39:30    278  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light    30
2019-12-17 03:40:00    279  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      wake   450
2019-12-17 03:47:30    280  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light  5700
```

is correctly group, but the mean is very strange, in fact, the output is:

```
2019-12-17 02:00:00  273.5  2520.0
2019-12-17 03:15:00  275.0   270.0
2019-12-17 03:30:00  277.5   217.5
2019-12-17 03:45:00  280.0  5700.0
```

Is correct for 02:00:00 but I really don't understand why to create new value on 03:15:00

because for me this data:

```
  2019-12-17 03:28:30    275  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      deep   270
    2019-12-17 03:33:00    276  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2     light    30
    2019-12-17 03:33:30    277  Z8RsBpxhnkebK5fvahVCmfV7icO2      deep   360
```

Should be :

```
2019-12-17 03:30:00  277.5   220
```

Because the three values are pretty near to 3:30, instead of create a new one at 3:15 (because is too much far respect 3:30).

Thanks,

Comment: you are creating bins of 15 mins so from 3:00 to 3:14:59 there is no entry and then from next bin 3:15:00 to 3:29:59 lies one entry which appear as it is.

Comment: Ah ok. I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,i think this would work

```
data =df.set_index('Time').resample('15min').agg({'sec':'mean','index':'mean', 'uid':'first' }).dropna()
```

Comment: Nope, the problem isn't to delete NaN value, is keep some data, that I don't want to apply mean. If you see, after resample disappear the data "uid", because with that value I cant apply mean.

Comment: updated, there must be a better way to do this but least i could do.

Comment: in case of same hours and ID different, I need to use groupby before? i tried this :
data =dataM.groupby('uid').resample('15min').agg({'sec':'mean', 'uid':'first' }).dropna()

but don't apply a correct resample

Comment: can you share some of that data and desired output may be update question